# ¿Cómo establecer ruta de componente Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

Desarrollo una aplicación angular y agregue un componente de nombre: editor-noticias

Ahora cuando ejecuto mi aplicación no encuentro la URL  para visualizar la página en el navegador.

editor-noticias.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-editor-noticias',
  templateUrl: './editor-noticias.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./editor-noticias.component.scss',
    "../../../../_shared/styles/modals.scss",
    "../../../../_shared/styles/tables.scss"]
})
```

home-editor-routing.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'editorHome',
    component: EditorComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'prueba',
    component: PruebaComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'editorNoticias',
    component: EditorNoticiasComponent
  },
];
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es por el orden en el arreglo de rutas. El path vacío `path: ''` debe ser el último.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a cambiar:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'editorHome',
    component: EditorComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'prueba',
    component: PruebaComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'editorNoticias',
    component: EditorNoticiasComponent
  },
];
```

Por esto:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'editorHome',
    component: EditorComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'prueba',
    component: PruebaComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'editorNoticias',
    component: EditorNoticiasComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: HomeComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

De esta manera no tendrás problemas ya que lo último que se cargará será el path en vacío.

Además te recomiendo llamar a ese path con un redirectTo en lugar de component:

```
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'
  }
```

en lugar de:

```
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  }
```

De esta forma te aseguras que estás en el sitio correcto y lo que hace es redirigirte a la ruta que deseas.